I need help to evaluate Integral :$\int^1_0\arctan(x)\ln(x)dx$
I need help to evaluate the integral :
$$\int^1_0\arctan(x)\ln(x)dx$$
Using
$$\arctan(x)=\int^1_0\frac{x}{1+(xy)^2 }dy$$
we have :
\begin{align}
I &= \int^1_0\arctan(x)\ln(x)dx=\int^1_0\int^1_0\frac{x\ln(x)}{1+(xy)^2}dxdy\\
&= \int^1_0\int^1_0\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^nx^{2n+1}y^{2n}\ln(x)dxdy\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left({\int^1_0x^{2n+1}\ln(x)dx}\right)\left({\int^1_0y^{2n}dy}\right)\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{4(2n+1)(n+1)^2}
\end{align}
How to evaluate the series:
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{4(2n+1)(n+1)^2}$$

Maybe a partial fraction expansion helps: $1/((2n+1)(n+1)^2)=4/(2n+1)-2/(n+1)-1/(n+1)^2$. The resulting series seem easier.

Thank you for a comment

Note that
$$\frac1{(2n+1)(n+1)^2}=\frac4{2n+1}-\frac2{n+1}-\frac1{(n+1)^2} $$
Hence the series is:
$$\frac14\sum_{n\ge 0}(-1)^{n+1}\left(\frac4{2n+1}-\frac2{n+1}-\frac1{(n+1)^2}\right) $$
Now split the series and use the expansion of $\arctan (x)$, $\log(1+x)$ and this result.

\begin{align*}
S &= \sum_{n\geq 1} \frac{(-1)^n}{n^2(2n-1)} \\
&= 2 \sum_{n \geq 1} (-1)^n \left( \frac{1}{2n-1} - \frac{1}{2n} \right) + \sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n^2}  \\
&= 2 \sum_{n \geq 1} (-1)^n \int_0^1 (x^{2n-2} - x^{2n-1}) \, dx  + \frac{1}{2} \zeta(2) \\
&= 2 \int_0^1 \left( \sum_{n \geq 1}(-1)^n x^{2n} \right) \left( \frac{1}{x^2} - \frac{1}{x} \right) \, dx + \frac{1}{2} \zeta(2) \\
&= 2 \int_0^1 \frac{x-1}{x^2 + 1} \, dx + \frac{1}{2} \zeta(2) \\
& = \ln(x^2 + 1) \bigg{|}_0^1 - \frac{\pi}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \zeta(2) \\
&= \ln(2) - \frac{\pi}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \zeta(2) \\
\end{align*}

As  @Sine of the Time did, consider
$$\frac1{4(2n+1)(n+1)^2}=\frac 1{2n+1}-\frac1{2(n+1)}-\frac1{4(n+1)^2}$$ Multiply each term by $(t^2)^{n+1}$ and you should get for the summation
$$t \tanh ^{-1}(t)+\frac{1}{2} \log \left(1-t^2\right)-\frac{1}{4}\text{Li}_2\left(t^2\right)$$
Let $t=i$ for the result

$$
\int^1_0\arctan(x)\ln(x) dx = \left[{x\arctan(x)(\ln(x)-1)}\right]^1_0-\int^1_0\frac{x\ln(x)}{1+x^2}dx+\int^1_0\frac{x}{1+x^2}dx
$$
$$=-\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\ln(2)+\frac{1}{4}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{48}-\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\ln(2)$$
$$\boxed{\int^1_0\arctan(x)\ln(x) dx =\frac{\pi^2}{48}-\frac{\pi}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\ln(2)}$$

Alternative method
Integrating the series for $|t|<1$
$$
\frac{1}{1+t^2}= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^n t^{2 n}
$$
from $t=0$ to $x$
$$
\arctan x=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n x^{2 n+1}}{2 n+1}
$$
Plugging back yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
I= & \int_0^1 \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n x^{2 n+1}}{2 n+1} \ln x d x \\
& =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{2 n+1} \int_0^1 x^{2 n+1} \ln x d x \\
& =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{2 n+1} \cdot \frac{-1}{4(n+1)^2} \\
& =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{4(2 n+1)(n+1)^2}\\ &=  \frac{1}{2} \ln 2+\frac{\pi^2}{48}-\frac{\pi}{4} 
\end{aligned}
$$

Nice solution +1) Thank you

We first resolve OP’s series into partial fractions and then express the individual sum into definite integrals.
$$
\begin{aligned} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{4(2 n+1)(n+1)^{2}} 
= & \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\left[\frac{1}{2} \cdot \frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}+\frac{1}{4} \cdot \frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)^2}+\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2 n+1}\right]\\= & \frac{1}{2} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n+1}+\frac{1}{4} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)^2}+\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{2 n+1}\\   =&\frac{1}{2} \int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x} d x-\frac{1}{4} \int_0^1 \frac{\log x}{1+x} d x-\int_0^1 \frac{1}{1+x^2} dx
\\ = & \frac{1}{2} \ln 2+\frac{\pi^2}{48}-\frac{\pi}{4} \\
\end{aligned}
$$
